# Best way to write DataTables from a Web Service into XML?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, datatable

I'm trying to refactor some slow running code which writes XML using nested loops of several datatables. I read that using linq to write the xml would be faster. I'm not well versed in linq, so I was hoping to get some help here.

Some things I need to mention is that the current architecture uses a webservice which returns data to us in dataTables. We then go through the datatables (iteratively), and there are several which results several nested loops.

example:

```
dt1 = Webservice.getStuff();

for each (datarow r1 in dt1.Rows) {

   dt2 = Webservice.getMoreStuff(r1[col1], r1[col2]);
   // write out some xml

   for each (datarow r2 in dt2.Rows) {

       dt3 = Webservice.getEvenMoreStuff(r2[col1], r2[col2]);
       // write out more xml 

       for each (datarow r3 in dt3.Rows) {
            // write out more xml 
       }

   }
}
```

As you can see for obvious reasons, this is terribly slow. Is there a way to speed this up using linq? What would you guys suggest as a more efficient approach to refactor this? I'm sorry if the details are vague...

I appreciate any help anyone could offer.

Comment: The slow part here seem to be the calls to WebService, not the XML writing part. WebService has a slow, high latency ring to it =)

Comment: just a thought: given current code snippet there is no details of how XML is created, plus there can be large amount of data sent over network, too many server calls, and client-side population of data tables - all could cause performance hit; so there is no apparent reason to assume that XML writing is a bottleneck.

Comment: Can you rewrite or add another getStuff method that gives you the full result instead of nesting webservice calls?

Comment: is it possible to rewrite your webservice to return a bigger result set which includes all the data you need for dt1, dt2 and dt3 - thats probably going to be your best performance increase

Comment: Have you done any profiling?  I would be curious how long the webservice calls take on their own without any XML writing--you might find that they're 98% of your delay and, if there's no room for altering them, that you can at best only increase performance by that 2%.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your advice and help. The reason why there are so many ws calls is for a couple of reasons:
1. We are forced to use webservices for the data retrieval.
2. I suggested condensing the calls, but the data is so large that even after increasing the maxreceivedmessagesize and maxbuffersize attribute values in the config file we still run the risk of exceeding that limit and losing data so we have to break them up into multiple calls which return pieces of data at a time.
I appreciate the suggestions, and I will try to refactor in some way to decrease the WS calls.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Writing the XML isn't what is slowing you down in this case**. That speed should be negligible compared to the time spent making all of the web service calls.

Instead of focusing on the writing of the XML, I would try to figure out how to compress the number of web service calls so you can get all your data at once rather than making nested calls like that.

Comment: web service call in any kind of big loop scares me

Comment: Yes, I agree that a serious problem is the webservice calls, but the problem is, I have no control over the webservice and I need to get information from each preceding call in order to make the call to the subsequent webservice methods.

Comment: @Johnny: but then asking for 'fastest write' isn't so useful.

Comment: @JohnnyQuest - My point, in that case, was that optimizing your XML writing is fairly pointless. You're really not going to see any benefit in performance (if that's what you're worried about)...assuming that you're not doing anything crazy in how you're writing it out (since you never show us that code).

Answer (score 4):

I am afraid there is no cure for your need. Because I am pretty sure what makes this method slow is not how you write out xml but the way you acquire the data. If there would be any improvment in writing out xml, it would not be in a noticable proportion. I suggest you to revise the way you acquire data. Try to minimize the number of WebService calls.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you need to profile your app first and foremost - maybe a free trial of [ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm) or similar will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Linq2Xml you'll also need Linq2Datasets.

That way you can change your nested for loops to a Linq query and select into XML.

I do expect that using a XmlWriter might be faster though, and will certainly use less memory. But it will be a little more work to write.

Comment: Why would he need Linq 2 Datasets?  Also what do you base the speed difference between Linq to XML and XMLWriter.

Comment: 1) You can't query DataRows without it.  And 2) XmlWriter writes directly, Linq2Xml builds a document first. Then uses an XmlWriter

Answer (score 1):

Using linq to xml and linq to datasets you can create your own xml like this:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {

      DataTable t = getStuff("test");

      var xml = new XElement("Main", from row in t.AsEnumerable()
                select new XElement("firstlevel",
                    new XAttribute("a", row["a"]),
                    new XAttribute("b", row["b"]),
                    from row2 in getStuff(row["a"].ToString()).AsEnumerable()
                    select new XElement("secondlevel",
                       new XAttribute("a", row2["a"]),
                       new XAttribute("b", row2["b"]),
                       from row3 in getStuff(row2["a"].ToString()).AsEnumerable()
                       select new XElement("thirdlevel",
                           new XElement("a", row3["a"]),
                           new XElement("b", row3["b"])))));

      Console.WriteLine(xml.ToString());


  }

  private static DataTable getStuff(string s)
  {
      Random r=new Random(s.GetHashCode());
      DataTable t = new DataTable();
      t.Columns.Add("a");
      t.Columns.Add("b");
      for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
      {
          t.Rows.Add (r.Next().ToString(), r.Next().ToString());
      }
      return t;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to re factor your solution a bit to get rid of all that looped WS calls. That is a serious performance downer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say how you are writing the XML or where you are writing the XML to.

If you are writing to a string. Stop that, and write a stream.

If you are writing to a buffered string, then look at the size of the buffer. If you are writing from an ASP.NET page or handler, then call Response.Flush() at regular intervals.

There's a balance here, as writing to a buffer is almost always faster than writing to a stream. However, writing to an automatically resizing buffer will get slower the more it has to resize. What's more, whatever is processing the XML can't begin to act until it starts to receive some, which won't happen until after the first flush.

There could therefore be scope for improvement here, though the calls to the webservice are likely to outweigh what gains can be made. Maybe this can be improved too, if you rewrite the parsing of the webservice's response so that it `yields` items as they are parsed, which means that you can start processing the response before the entire response is received.